# binded objects not compiling on VS2015

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, visual-studio-2015, libtorrent

In `libtorrent` I found the following code, which does not compile with Visual Studio 2015 RC:

```
boost::bind( &address::is_v4,
             boost::bind( &tcp::endpoint::address,
                          _1
             )
)
== m_bind_addr.is_v4()
```

While we may debate the questionable use of operator overloading with bind, I actually wonder, why it does not compile. The error message is:

```
C:\Projects\boost\boost/bind/bind.hpp(2003): error C2027: use of undefined type 'boost::_bi::add_cref<Pm,0>'
          with
          [
              Pm=bool (__thiscall boost::asio::ip::address::* )(void) const
          ]
  C:\Projects\boost\boost/bind/bind.hpp(2011): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::_bi::dm_result<M (__thiscall boost::asio::ip::address::* ),A1>' being compiled
          with
          [
              M=bool (void) const,
              A1=boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::asio::ip::address,boost::_mfi::cmf0<boost::asio::ip::address,boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::tcp>>,boost::_bi::list1<boost::arg<1>>>
          ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this but only for 32 bit compiles. 64-bit was fine. Surrounding the function with mem_fn (from boost/mem_fn.hpp) did the trick:

```
boost::bind( &address::is_v4,
         boost::bind( boost::mem_fn( &tcp::endpoint::address),
                      _1
         )
) == m_bind_addr.is_v4()
```